# Excel Run Time Error 424 - Object required

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a VBA code that is going to allow me type in text in a textfield which will filter the column. However, when I type something, I receive this error box (look at the picture).

I am following this tutorial, it works fine for him: [Dynamic Filter in Excel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ucjVR6-8zX8)

[image]

Here is the VBA code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

If Len(Texbox1.Value) = 0 Then
    Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
Else
    If Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = True Then
        Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
        Sheet1.Range("A2:C" & Rows.Count).AutoFilter field:=1,  Criteria1:="*" & TextBox1.Value & "*"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a simple typo. Your textbox is named `TextBox1` but you refer to it as `Texbox1`.